# Get Ajax Json Output with Python Requests Library 500 error

Tags: python, ajax, json

I have done this code to get an output form the web page of http://www.yurticikargo.com/bilgi-servisleri/Sayfalar/en-yakin-sube.aspx
but I receive 500 error. Could not understand why

```
import requests
import json


class Yurtici(object):
    baseUrl = 'http://www.yurticikargo.com/'
    ajaxRoot1 = '_layouts/ArikanliHolding.YurticiKargo.WebSite/ajaxproxy-sswservices.aspx/'
    ajaxRoot2 = '_layouts/ArikanliHolding.YurticiKargo.WebSite/ajaxproxy-unitservices.aspx/GetUnit'

    getTown = 'GetTownByCity'

    urlGetTown = baseUrl + ajaxRoot1 + getTown
    urlGetUnit = baseUrl + ajaxRoot2  
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','encoding':'utf-8'}

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ilceler(self, plaka=34): # Default testing value
        payload = {'cityId':plaka}
        url = self.urlGetTown
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=self.headers)
        return r.json() # OK


    def subeler(self, ilceNo=3401): # Default testing value
        # 5902 Çerkezköy 
        payload=  {'cityID':34,'townID':ilceNo,'unitOnDutyFlag':'null','closestFlag':0}
        url = self.urlGetUnit
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','encoding':'utf-8'}
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        return r.json()
        print  r.status_code, r.raw.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    a = Yurtici()
   #print a.ilceler(34) # OK
    print a.subeler()   # NOT OK !!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just on a hunch, I found a problem with the `'unitOnDutyFlag'` value. When encoding a python `dict` to json, if you want `null` in the output, you should have a value of `None` in the dict.

Try changing the line:

```
payload = {'cityID':34,'townID':ilceNo,'unitOnDutyFlag':'null','closestFlag':0}
```

to:

```
payload = {'cityID':34,'townID':ilceNo,'unitOnDutyFlag': None,'closestFlag':0}
```

#### Example:

```python
# nulljson.py
import json

data = {
    'foo': 'null',
    'bar': None
}

print json.dumps(data)
```

Output:

```
$ python nulljson.py
{"foo": "null", "bar": null}
```

Note that the value of `"foo"` is the *string* `"null"`, not the true `null` value.